# Setup of maven plugin for using QueryDSL with a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, maven, maven-plugin, querydsl

I'm trying to setup my project so that I can use querydsl-sql against a MySQL database.
I'd like to get the classes and generate the classes using maven and am having problems setting up the plugin.

I've tried configuring the pom.xml from the example available [here](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>
        <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql:mydb:3306/alltrades</jdbcUrl>
        <jdbcUser>mvaz</jdbcUser>
        <packageName>com.three60t.tools.bonus.persistence</packageName>
        <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The dependency to mysql-connector-java is also given in the pom.
The problem that I'm getting is that it doesn't seem to find the driver:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tools-bonus
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [querydsl:export {execution: default}]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:mydb:3306/alltrades
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at com.mysema.query.maven.AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.execute(AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:mydb:3306/alltrades

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 01 16:34:47 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me with this?
How can I specify the driver?

Comment: Except for the url we use similar parameters in production without issues, could you use give us an anonymized version of your JDBC url?

Comment: Wow, attention is really a selective process. It really was an error with the URL as you guys said. Somehow I was ignoring the missing double slashes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies seem to be correct, but your JDBC URL looks funky. Try `<jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alltrades</jdbcUrl>`. The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) states the following:

> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
>   [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.

You also might need to specify a `jdbcPassword`. For other options look at the [Querydsl Reference Manual](http://source.mysema.com/static/querydsl/2.1.1/reference/html/ch02s04.html#d0e667).

Comment: 2) No password needed in this case, unless the plugin requires it.I will check the documentation, thanks.

Comment: So you have specified the URL in the above format? I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is specified correctly, if the driver would be wrong you would get a different Exception :

```
Class.forName(jdbcDriver); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword);
```

Does this also fail in isolation? It looks like an error in the jdbcUrl format.